# Web-Form not accepting responses(Asp.net)

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, backend, web-development-server

Recently i am working on a **web-form** written in **asp.net framework**. I have kept in mind to include `!IsPostBack()` but yet my form is not accepting the responses and updating the database accordingly.
The body of the **.aspx** code which basically contains **4 RadioButtonList and one textbox**. Here is the code for one of the RadioButtonList and the textBox, the submit button and and a link button:

```
<li class="form-line jf-required" data-type="control_scale" id="id_24">
                    <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_24" for="input_24">
                        Do you feel the training provided value for money/time?
     
                    <span class="form-required">*
                    </span>
                </label>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Font-Size="Large" Height="50px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" class="radiobuttonlist1">Worse</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" class="radiobuttonlist2">Boring</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" class="radiobuttonlist3">Satisfactory</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" class="radiobuttonlist4">good</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5" class="radiobuttonlist5">Fantastic</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </li>

            <li id="cid_27" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
                <div class="form-header-group  header-default">
                    <div class="header-text httal htvam">
                        <h2 id="header_27" class="form-header" data-component="header">Final Thoughts?
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="form-line" data-type="control_textarea" id="id_45">
                <label class="form-label form-label-top form-label-auto" id="label_45" for="input_45">REMARKS / SUGGESTIONS</label>
                <div id="cid_45" class="form-input-wide" data-layout="full">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="width: 40px; height: 6px"></asp:TextBox>                        
                </div>
            </li>

            <li id="cid_28" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
                <div align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" Text-align="center" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Button1_Click" BackColor="#66FFCC" Height="40px" Width="80px" />
                </div>
                <div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-link" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Go back to Home Page</asp:LinkButton>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
```

**Here is the .aspx.cs of Page_Load:**

```
public MySqlConnection mycon;
    public MySqlCommand MyCm, cmd1;
    public MySqlDataAdapter myad;
    string userId;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       userId= Session["newFeedback"].ToString();
        try
        {
            mycon = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=feedbackform;user id=abcd;password=abcdabcd;");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Here is the .aspx.cs code for Button_Click:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Check_feedback_Exists())
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('You have already filled feedback form')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {

                    if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)    
                    {
                        mycon.Open();
                    }
                   
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into feedback (Reference_Number, Feed1,Feed2,Feed3,Feed4,Remarks_Suggestion)values(userId, RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text,RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text,RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text,RadioButtonList4.SelectedItem.Text,Textbox1.Text);", mycon);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                       
                    mycon.Close();
                    Response.Write("<script> alert ('hello success'); </Script>");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script> alert ('" + ex.Message + "'); </Script>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is the code for the Check_feedback_exists:**

```
bool Check_feedback_Exists()
    {
        try
        {

            if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)    //checking that the connection between database and our project is open or not if not then open it 
            {
                mycon.Open();
            }

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from feedback where Reference_Number = '" + userId + "' ; ", mycon);
            
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script> alert ('" + ex.Message + "'); </script>");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

The check_feedback_exists function is working well since if i submit for an already existing feedback, it gives the alert message: 'You have already filled feedback form' as coded in the Button1_click function. But if i enter a new feedback for a new user and click on submit, it doesn't enter the database, neither shows the success alert. Here is the database description in which I am inserting these values:

[image: feedback table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes no sense to check !IsPostBack in a button click. Such a button click will ALWAYS be a post-back. So, that's confusing.

And same goes for your sql insert. Your trying to insert the "text" of the control.

eg this:

```
        string strSQL =
            "insert into feedback (Reference_Number, Feed1, Feed2, Feed3, Feed4, Remarks_Suggestion) " + 
            "VALUES (@userId, @RB1,@RB2,@RB3,@RB4,@TBOX1"


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@usewrId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RB1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RB2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text;
```

etc. etc. etc.

Now, I used the sql provider, - it looks like your using MySQL. But, the sytnax should be simular to above. So, for your insert, you can't use a string of

```
string strSQL = "textBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text"
```

Since that string will have the above textbox names as string.

You would need

```
string strSQL = "VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')"
```

But, the above is dangerous - due to sql injection. So use the above parameters approach.

And remove the !IsPostBack from your button stubb - not required, and a button click is ALWAYS a post-back anyway.

Comment: ;( thanks a lot!! i keep forgetting to put in the inverted commas, and sorry for the !isPostBack on button(that was an emotional try after frustration)